# Access controller constructor by controller name in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller name as string and I want to get constructor of it.

My current method is using $controller as below:

```
$scope.myControllerConstructor= $controller( "myControllerName" , {$scope: $scope.$new()}).constructor;
```

Later on, I use this constructor in the html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myControllerConstructor">
```

The issue is my controller runs two time, one time when I get the constructor (which is wrong) and one time when my html gets compiled (which is correct)

The question is how to get the controller constructor without running it?

---

**Update about use-case**: In our application we have many pages with 60% similarities and 40% different activities. I created a directive for those pages and other developers in the team are using my directive to create their page.

The directive accepts a template and a controller (I get them as string) and later on I include the provided template and controller as below:

```
<div ng-include="myTemplate" ng-controller="myControllerConstructor"></div>
```

Please take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5so1h3h/2/) for a simple example of issue.

Comment: Approach doesn't make much sense. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If you're using it for controller inheritance, I would suggest to update the title and the question to match your case, this would make it clear and easier to find on SO.

Comment: The delayed instatiation API is private and not intended to be used by applications. There are many ways to abuse the AngularJS framework. Using it in an unstructured manner often results in a fragile application that is a maintenance nightmare. So what is your use case? Maybe there is a better structured way to accomplish it.

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the use-case

Comment: still doesn't explain the concept behind trying to use `myControllerConstructor`. Are you wanting to evaluate `ng-controller` attribute to dynamically add controller? Suggest you provide a demo that gives an indication of the issue

Comment: @charlietfl, I created a simple jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5so1h3h/2/

Comment: why can't you just put `ng-controller` inside each template? Demo still doesn't give indication of higher level problem you are trying to solve using standard approaches. Also what router are you using? If using ui-router can nest views and define controllers in routing config

Comment: That is correct, I can ask developers to put ng-controller inside their templates instead of passing it to my directive and it works fine. I am going to use that approach for now. But in higher level, if my directive provides the template and developers only pas controller name to my directive. Then the issue still exists.

Comment: There's XY problem. You cannot get controller constructor without instantiating it first, this is how framework works. It isn't clear from the question, why can't it be a component/directive (even if they are supplied by the other party)? This is what directives really are - a controller plus a template. Thinkng of a controller as of a separate entity is obsolete and bad habit in Angular development. A fiddle doesn't really explain why it should be this way and not the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your code looks ok but the issue is `$controller( "myControllerName" , {$scope: $scope.$new()})` already instantiate the controller with the given scope for you.

It is true that you can access the controller constructor with `.constructor` but it is too late as you already created an instance of the controller.

[ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) does the exact same thing as `$controller( "myControllerName" , {$scope: $scope.$new()})`

> When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller
>   directive, AngularJS will instantiate a new Controller object, using
>   the specified Controller's constructor function. A new child scope
>   will be created and made available as an injectable parameter to the
>   Controller's constructor function as $scope.

To solve this issue you should pass **the controller constructor function** to `pageDirectiveTemplate` instead of the controller name.

The [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5so1h3h/8/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way we can achieve this. In directive, while using isolated scope (like you are doing here in fiddle), you could have a property `controller` that has value `"@"` and have another `name` property having the value of `"myController"` or whatever your controller name you are passing as.

So, your directive could look something like this:

```
app.directive('pageDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    templateUrl: "pageDirectiveTemplate",
    scope: {
      myTemplate: "@"
    },
    controller: "@",
    name: "myController"
  }
});
```

Notice that, only change in HTML would be to have the directive as an attribute instead of an element. So,

```
<div page-directive my-template="templateA" my-controller="controllerA">
</div>
<div page-directive my-template="templateA" my-controller="controllerB">
</div>
```

This would give you exactly what you are looking for. Now you can have same template pointing different controllers and vice-versa.

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1a6ujhn9/) | Note that it works for two different controllers having same template. Also, check the console to see how it logs only once from each controller.

Comment: It is nice, but the issue is we are sharing the controller with "pageDirectiveTemplate" and "templateA". pageDirectiveTemplate controller is static and has shared logic in it. however, myController is dynamic.

Comment: @Arashsoft, oh shoot.. So let me get this clear.. You want to share a dynamic controller (say `controllerA`) with a static one (`pageDirectiveTemplate`) for some dynamic template. Right?

Comment: "pageDirective" has its own controller and template (they are static). Inside the "pageDirectiveTemplate", I want to inject a dynamic template with dynamic controller. Currently I am using `<div ng-include="myTemplate" ng-controller="myControllerConstructor"></div>`  which works fine but the controller runs two time.